# How can I link a string from one to another Class?

Tags: java, android, string

I have two Java Classes. 
"Stickers.java" which is only a Java class.
"KeyboardService" which is the activity class.

I have a String inside "Stickers.java" which needs to be overwritten from the activity java class "KeyboardService" by two button.

How can I do it?

I want to change the String "PACK_LIB" from "Stickers.java" by clicking Buttons. The first Button "b1" will overwrite the "PACK_LIB" with "allstickers" and the other button "b2" with "teststickers".

But how can I tell "KeyboardService.java" where the String is. Because it is in a different java class?

// Stickers.java

```
public void setDefaultStickerPack() {
    checkVersion(true);
    InputStream in = null;
    String packList[]=new String[0];
    String PACK_LIB = "";
    final String PACK_APP="pack_app";
    final String PACK_ICON="pack_on.png";
    String curAssets="";
```

// KeyboardService.java

```
    final String[] PACK_LIB = {""};

    final Button button1 = (Button) mainBoard.findViewById(R.id.b1);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            PACK_LIB[0] = "allstickers";
        }
    });
    final Button button2 = (Button) mainBoard.findViewById((R.id.b2));
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            PACK_LIB[0] = "teststickers";
        }
    });
```

I also tried to import the java class "Stickers.java" into "KeyboardService" . But it doesnt work propably, it will not find the String "Pack_LIB" from "Stickers.java".

Comment: It's not in a different Java class, it's in a different Java method **and** it is ***local*** to that method.

Comment: So what can I do?

Comment: There are several ways you can do this.  One way is to create a third class that holds references to the other two classes.  You can then share data between the classes as you see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PACK_LIB is a local variable to the setDefaultStickerPack() method.  Change your code to the following and you should be able to see PACK_LIB from another class.

```
public String PACK_LIB = "";
public void setDefaultStickerPack() {
    checkVersion(true);
    InputStream in = null;
    String packList[]=new String[0];
    final String PACK_APP="pack_app";
    final String PACK_ICON="pack_on.png";
    String curAssets="";
```

Comment: Thanks so much ! :) But now i got two values and when I want to override it , it says -> variable PACK_LIB is already defined in class Stickers
    public String PACK_LIB = "";